# Apache to serve local address from another RPi

Tags: apache-httpd

Is it possible for a RPi server to serve from another RPi on the same network?

I have 2 RPi's on my home network, both running apache servers - *Raspberry A* is linked to a web domain i.e. `mydomain.net`, and the router redirects incoming http/https calls to it; *Raspberry B* is only available inside the network at network IP `192.168.1.123`.  If possible I'd like to create a html/php page on Raspberry A that relays calls to/from Raspberry B's network IP.  Grateful for any advice on how to achieve this.

Comment: IHMO - no simple way -try to read this... https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/4.2.x/admin/reverse-proxy-http-redirects.en.html  However, I would create a simple python webserver on B that - each call - would make a call to A and copied the response.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a **reverse proxy**. The apache docs explain it in detail here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Essentially, you need `mod_proxy` enabled and then you can use the **ProxyPass** directive.

Example (from the docs):

`ProxyPass "/images"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/images"  "http://www.example.com/"`

> In the above, any requests which start with the /images path with be
>   proxied to the specified backend, otherwise it will be handled
>   locally.

Note: The `ProxyPassReverse` is used to make sure that the displayed URLs that make it back to the client are for the proxy not the (unreachable directly) back end server.

Comment: Just picking this up again. The guidance seems to leave quite a bit inferred. Where is this example supposed to go - /etc/apache2/apache2.conf? Inside directory tags? Do I need to create a directory in web path to link the setting to? Does it need to include anything? I'm probably over-complicating it, but this documentation does seem light..

Comment: In `sites-available/default` (or the `.conf` file for the particular site, if you're hosting multiple) inside the **<VirtualHost>** element create a **<Location>** element and add the two directive above inside that.